# Set default height of rows in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, height, cell, tablelayoutpanel

How can I set default height of all `TableLayoutPanel` rows in c# to 16px?

Usually I would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount_of_rows; i++)
{
    panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16));
}
```

But in my case I have 8 columns and unknown amount of rows. Amount on rows is known after all controls are added, not before.

This is my code:

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel
{
    BackColor = SystemColors.Control,
    CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single,
    AutoScroll = true,
    Width = 500,
    Location = new Point(-1, -1),
    ColumnCount = 8
};
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 73));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 73));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 38));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 38));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 52));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 52));

int amountOfRows = 0;
for (...)
{
    // a lot of code which populates panel with generated controls and counts amountOfRows
}
panel.RowCount = amountOfRows;
Controls.Add(panel);
```

Such code creates rows with 24px height.

Adding ColumnStyles to table after it was populated like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRows ; i++)
{
    panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16));
}
```

works but it makes last row very large.

EDIT: example code including adding a control:

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel
{
    BackColor = SystemColors.Control,
    CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single,
    AutoScroll = true,
    Width = 500,
    Location = new Point(-1, -1),
    ColumnCount = 8,
    Margin = new Padding(0),
    Padding = new Padding(0)
};
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 73));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 73));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 38));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 38));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 52));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 52));

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // lets assume we don't know it will be added 10x
{
    CheckBox exchangeEnabled = new CheckBox
    {
        Margin = new Padding(0),
        Padding = new Padding(0),
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    };
    panel.Controls.Add(exchangeEnabled, 0, i);
}
Controls.Add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the reason you get cells with a height of 24 pixels is that you are adding controls with a height of 16 pixels.

Unless you change the values the default `Margin` and `Padding` values are 3 pixels for all sides.

This will result in 2x3 + 2x3 extra pixels, adding up to a total height of 24 pixels for the cells.

To control the height you should not only control the height of the controls you add, but also of the TLP's `Padding` and the child's `Margin` values.

This is also a way to enlarge rows or columns and the only way I know of aligning/placing controls in a pixel perfect way..

> [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
>
> The docking behavior of child controls is the same as other container controls.
>
> The anchoring behavior of child controls in a TableLayoutPanel differs
>   from the behavior in other container controls. If the value of the
>   child control's Anchor property is set to Left or Right, the control
>   will be placed against the left or right border of the cell, at a
>   distance that is the sum of the control's Margin property and the
>   panel's Padding property. If both the Left and Right values are set,
>   the control will be sized to the width of the cell, with the Margin
>   and Padding values taken into account. The behavior for Top and Bottom
>   anchoring is analogous. For more information, see How to: Anchor and
>   Dock Child Controls in a TableLayoutPanel Control.
>
> If you need a child control to mimic the default anchoring behavior in
>   other container controls, you can adjust the Margin and Padding
>   properties to maintain a constant distance between the control's
>   border and the cell's border.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't change anything. I added Margin = new Padding(0), Padding = new Padding(0) to TableLayoutPanel and its controls. I added an example code including adding a control. Or didn't I completely understand you?

Comment: Hm, no, you got me right. Can you see the influence when setting a large padding/margin? - What are the max. heights? By default a CheckBox has autosize on, so the height will depend on the Fontsize.

Comment: Setting Height = 16 on all controls made. Even when margin and padding are 0 it still adds some space around for some reason. After specifying exact height it works. Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: At the end I did it by running another loop at the beginning which counts amount of rows and adds 16px rows prior to adding controls. I had to do it like that because it is not possible to change textbox size which is single line. It is only possible to set multiline textbox size which I don't want. Winforms is apparently not ad advanced as css ;).